# How to iterate over files extract file name and pass to pandas logic

Tags: pandas

I have a folder called "before_manipulation ". 
It contains 3 CSV  files with names `File_A.CSV`, `File_B.CSV` ,`File_C.CSV`

Current_path : `c:/users/before_manipulation`  `[file_A.CSV, File_B.CSV,File_C.CSV]`

I have a data manipulation that I need to do in each of the files and after manipulation ,I need to save with the same file names in another directory.

Targeted_path : `C:/users/after_manipulation`  `[file_A.CSV, File_B.CSV,File_C.CSV]`

I have the logic to do the  data manipulation when there is only a single file with Pandas dataframe. When I have multiple files, how to read each file and its name and pass it to my logic ?

Pseudo Code of how I am working if there was one file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('c:/users/before_manipulation/file_A.csv')
... do logic/manipulation
df.to_csv('c:/users/after_manipuplation/file_A.csv')
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir(<path>)` to return a list of the files contained within a directory.  If you do not pass a variable to `<path>` it will return the working directory listing.

With the list from `os.listdir` you can iterate over it, passing the capture filename to the function you already have for data manipulation.  Then on the save to you can use the captured filename to save in your desired directory.

In summary the code would look something like this.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

in_dir = r'c:/users/before_manipulation/'
out_dir = r'c:/users/after_manipulation/'

files_to_run = os.listdir(in_dir)

for file in files_to_run:
    print('Running {}'.format(in_dir + file))
    df = pd.read_csv(in_dir + file)
    ...do your logic here to return the changed df you want to save
    ...
    df.to_csv(out_dir + file)
```

For this to work you would need to have the same shape files for each file you have in the directory, and also you would need to want to do the same logic for each file.

If that is not the case you will need something like a dictionary to save the different manipulations you need to do based on the file name and call those when appropriate.

Comment: am getting error when i use the above logic :                                                         ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 16, saw 7

Comment: Glad that it worked for you...Please accept it as the answer so people will know it worked for you!

Comment: How to accept this as answer ? i didnt find any Accept button in the page ?

Comment: @KalyanT there should be a gray check mark next to my answer.  Simply select it to make it go from gray to green.  This will indicate accepted.  Here is the help page if you need more info. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some logic that works for one file, I'd just put that logic into a function and run it on a for loop.

You'd end up with something like this:

```
directory = r'c:/users/before_manipulation'

files = ['file_A.CSV', 'File_B.CSV','File_C.CSV']

for file in files:
    somefunction(directory + '/' + file)
```

If you need more info on functions I'd check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

using `pathlib`

```
from pathlib import Path
new_dir = '\\your_path' 
files = [file for file in Path(your_dir).glob('*.csv')]
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    # .. your logic
    df.to_csv(f'{new_dir}\\{file.name}',index=False)
```